# What is post traversal of forest

Tags: algorithm

Can someone explain it in detail?(it's forest ,not binary tree)
I'm reading the tree and forest chapter of data structure book,I've known the pre order traversal and in order traversal of forest.

Comment: "*What is post traversal of forest*" ... "*I've known the post order traversal and in order traversal of forest.*" ... So you know it or don't? Btw, forest *is* a data structure, so "forest in Data Structure" is rather redundant in your question.

Comment: Sorry,I just typed wrong.I meaned that I've known the pre-order and in-order traversal,not the post-order traversal.

Answer (score 0):

Post traversal is a kind of method to explore your tree or forest.

in detail, post traversal mean you will explore nodes nearest to the leaf including the leaf itself.

In action; you should always go to your first or leftmost node until the current node does not have any child. if that occurs, you do your actions with the note , go to his parent, go to "his next son" and the you keep going deep into that node repeting the process (first leftmost child, etc...).

[Heres an image that can help you understand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first)